# SAS - Write filenames to a dataset, or to an external file?

Tags: dataset, sas, filenames

Is there a way, in SAS, to grab filenames (.txt files) from a directory (e.g. c:\temp) and write them to a dataset? Or possibly to write them into a separate .txt. file?

I'm trying to find some examples online but haven't been able to locate anything.

Comment: What operating system is your SAS installation on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way to do this is with a `named pipe`, which you can then read from.

Eg:

```
filename mydir pipe 'dir c:\temp\*.txt /b';
data mydata;
infile mydir lrecl=150 truncover;
input @1 line $150.;
run;
```